# Why does Stan initialize an MCMC chain with a random value generated uniformly from [-2, 2] instead of a random value generated from the prior?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, stan, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

From [Stan reference](https://mc-stan.org/rstan/reference/stan.html),

> The default is to randomly generate initial values between -2 and 2 on
>   the unconstrained support

It seems to me that it makes more sense to randomly generate initial values from the prior. A priori, I'm saying that I believe that these values make the most sense. Starting an MCMC chain from somewhere that has a possibly minuscule a priori probability doesn't intuitively make sense to me.

What is the reason for Stan's default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest problem with drawing from the prior is if a user is using a rather flat prior. For example, if a user is using a logistic regression model and they don't want the prior to have much of an effect on the posterior, they may choose to make the prior a normal distribution with a standard deviation of 100. Taking a draw from this prior will, with very high probability, lead to numerical errors (i.e., `NaN`) in computing the likelihood.

As such, the Stan authors are betting that values in the range $[-2, 2]$ are less likely to lead to computational errors than a draw from the prior.

Comment: I like that you say that this is a "bet"

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat: isn't that the proper definition of probability in Bayesian statistics: acceptable betting odds?